# Looking for ARM Cortex A9 board which doesn't have NEON

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, neon

I am in search of an ARM board which does not support NEON SIMD acceleration. Is there such a board ? I have a raspberry pi 2 and 3 and both of them support NEON SIMD.

Thanks

Comment: Why? If you write code which doesn't use NEON, that code doesn't use NEON. Whether it's present in the hardware or not doesn't matter.

Comment: please read the updated answer.

Comment: Are you trying to test feature detection logic or something?  It might be cheaper to use an emulator, if there's one that supports switching features on and off.

Comment: Yes. I would like to see how an ARM board without NEON will complain when it's executing NEON code. Is there an online emulator available ?

Comment: When building for an ARMv7 target with NEON enabled, GCC will add some NEON instructions to plain old C code even if it isn't "vectorizing" anything. This will cause an illegal instruction exception on hardware (e.g. ARMv6) which doesn't support the instruction set.

Answer (score 3):

NEON is optional in Cortex-A9 devices. You don't really have to use it.
Here is a comparison of all [single-board computers available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_single-board_computers). You can choose whatever you want from the list.

**EDIT:**

One thing I'd like to mention is ARMv6 architecture doesn’t include NEON engine while ARMv7 architecture does. Both `Raspberry Pi 1` and `Raspberry Pi Zero` uses `ARMv6 (32-bit)`, hence they do not support `NEON`.

You can also read [this topic on Raspberry Pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=99799), where someone managed to run `armv6` Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 2 which is `ARMv7` architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated comments, you probably should be looking at QEMU.  This is the open source simulator that supports ARM.  This should allow you to do all the functional testing for every type of ARM you can think of, and is a very valuable tool. Once you get to performance testing, then yes, you can just compile without NEON support and instructions and run on your raspberry pi.

http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM

While solidpixel's answer is downvoted for not being an SOC, You can find Tegra 2 dev boards if you decide you would like to have actual hardware.  I'm not sure I can think of a good reason for this, but if your financial resources and purpose leads you down this path, elinux.com has a few suggestions here: http://elinux.org/Tegra2

Answer (score -2):

IIRC the Nvidia Tegra 2 was a Cortex-A9 which didn't have NEON (most others did). List of devices using Tegra 2 on the wikipedia page:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegra

Comment: its not a single board computer though